# MySQL - extract value in brackets [...]

Tags: mysql, string, extract

I need to extract the values from the string that starts with `[` and ends with `]`.

For example:

```
abcdef [1.2.3.4] ghijkl
```

I need to extract only `1.2.3.4` from the string above. How do I perform this? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('abcdef [1.2.3.4] ghijkl', '[', -1), ']', 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work .

The `INSTR()` function get the position of the first occurrence of a string in another string.

SO we can use like below to get the string inside the this [] bracket .

```
$str = 'abcdef [1.2.3.4] ghijkl';

SUBSTRING($str ,INSTR($str ,"[") + 1, INSTR($str,"]"));
```